# Removing time from datetime and insert into db table using Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, postgresql-9.1, xlrd, python-datetime

Prior to asking a question I tried different ways and none worked.

I tried using datetime.strptime and dateutil, neither worked or I am doing it incorrectly.
I even tried splitting date into y, m, d variables and change to ints and then tried adding all 3 variables together for a full date variable.

How do I need to update the coding for the date portion, so I can read and insert values from the second/third/etc. columns with no errors?

I am having issues with Excel date and changing to postgres date. (The date field in the Excel has date and time. I only need the date portion.) I am reading a date column with xlrd and changing the date to what I need and insert, but once I add another column to read and insert, I receive code issues.

```
import psycopg2
import xlrd
import datetime
#Tried from datetime import datetime


try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(user = '', password = '', host =’’, database =’’, port = 0000)
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    print('DB connection open')
    print('Running SQL query')

    #Open the excel
    book = xlrd.open_workbook('name.xlsx')

    #Open the workbook sheet
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Date')

    query = """INSERT INTO table_name(
    date,
    second_column
    )

    VALUES(
    %s,
    %s)"""

    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        db_date = year_date = []
        date = sheet.cell(r, 0).value

        #Changing Excel date from m/d/y to y-m-d
        date_mode = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(review_date, book.datemode))
        start_date_full = date_mode
        split_start_date_full = str(start_date_full)

        #Splitting date to remove the time portion
        split_start_date_full = split_start_date_full.split(" ")

        #Adding the date to a list
        year_date = split_start_date_full[0]
        db_date.append((year_date))
        #Assign values to each row
        values = (
            db_date,
            second_column
            )
        mycursor.execute(query, values)


    #Commit to the DB. Close the mycursor and conn.
    mycursor.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print('''All done!''')

except Exception as e:
    #making sure cursor and conn is closed if I hit the except
    mycursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print(e)
```

Errors/results:
Inserts no problem if I only call the date column
*the second date value is only a date column in postgres db table that inserts a date based on when rows were inserted.*

```
>>>
================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
DB connection open
Running SQL query
(9616, datetime.date(2017, 12, 6), None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.date(2018, 1, 4))
All done!

I receive text error when I call a second/third/etc. columns
>>>
================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
DB connection open
Running SQL query
column "review_date" is of type date but expression is of type text[]
LINE 6:     ARRAY['2017-12-06'],
            ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
>>>
```

Comment: I do apologize, I did forget to add the code in the for loop for the second column to read from the Excel. This would have been after all of the code for the date.
second_column = sheet.cell(r, 1).value

Comment: I figured out how to make this work (I am new to Python coding and I figure it out as I go. If this makes sense. I assume I need to add my answer as an answer. If I am wrong, that is fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Steps I took:

1. I split year_date and put into year_date_full variable.
2. I created a variable for year, month, and day and turned into int's full_date
3. Then I combined year+-+month+-+day into its own variable and called that variable as the value that needs to be inserted into the db table.

---

```
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    db_date = year_date = []
    #Date Column A
    date = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
    date_mode = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(review_date, book.datemode))
    start_date_full = date_mode
    split_start_date_full = str(start_date_full)
    split_start_date_full = split_start_date_full.split(" ")
    year_date = split_start_date_full[0]
    time_date = split_start_date_full[1]
    #Split year_date '-' and put each section into its own variable
    year_date_full = year_date.split('-')
    start_year = year_date_full[0]
    start_month = year_date_full[1]
    start_day = year_date_full[2]
    #Turn str to a int for year, month, day
    full_date = (int(start_year),int(start_month),int(start_day))
    #created a new variable to hold the full year and '-'
    full_date_new = (start_year+'-'+start_month+'-'+start_day)
    #Second Column - Column B
    second_column = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
```

Insert results:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
DB connection open
Running SQL query
(12621, **datetime.date(2017, 12, 6)**, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, **False**, None, None, datetime.date(2018, 1, 5))
All done!
>>>
```